# Android Parse Cache not working

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform

I'm trying to use cache policy in my complex query, that fetches data from different tables. Everything works fine, but I'm unable to cache the data. Below is the code.

```
 mainQuery=getAllRoutesQuery();// fetches the complex query by combining multiple queries.
 mainQuery.setCachePolicy(CachePolicy.CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
 boolean flag = finalQuery.hasCachedResult(); //always return false
 mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
       //call back operations.
 }
```

I'm using ParseObject to query the data not a custom class extending from the ParseObject. getAllRoutesQuery only combines two subqueries.

```
private ParseQuery  getAllRoutesQuery(){
    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    //current user query
    ParseQuery query_CurrentUser = new ParseQuery(
                TravelDetails.t_tablename);
        query_CurrentUser.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(
                TravelDetails.f_departureDate, new java.util.Date());
        query_CurrentUser.whereEqualTo("userId", ParseObject
                .createWithoutData("_User", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                        .getObjectId()));

   //query to fetch friends
   ParseQuery query_Friends = new ParseQuery(TravelDetails.t_tablename);
            query_Friends.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(
                    TravelDetails.f_departureDate, new java.util.Date());
            query_Friends.whereContainedIn("userId",
                    HomeActivity.myFsFriendsList);
            query_Friends.whereNotEqualTo(TravelDetails.f_isDeleted,
                    Boolean.TRUE);
    queries.add(query_CurrentUser);
    queries.add(query_Friends);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
        "Route");
    mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
    mainQuery.include("userId._User");
    mainQuery.orderByDescending(TravelDetails.f_createdAt);
    mainQuery.setSkip(routeList.size());
    mainQuery.setLimit(limit += 20);
    return mainQuery;
}
```

Is it possible to have caching enabled on complex queries? Do I need to enable Caching on subqueries as well?

Comment: What are query_CurrentUser and query_Friends ? Can you include them in the question?

Comment: Try again after commenting out the mainQuery.setLimit(limit += 20); line

Comment: @Handsomeguy It's not working. I checked that.

Comment: @nauman ..check this link https://parse.com/questions/cache-doesnt-exist-for-or-query-android

Comment: @KP_ Thanks, that makes sense. I'll try to modify my query structure to achieve caching. Thanks! :)

Comment: @nauman ..Ok Nauman Naseer .Waiting for more updates from this app :)

Comment: @KP_ You can checkout www.friendshippr.com to check the app! :)